# How to get the latest labeled code and label name in TFS2013 using powershell

Tags: powershell, tfs

I am trying to get the latest labeled code for specific solution/project in TFS 2013 using PowerShell. If anyone knows how to get the latest label, please post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below script to get the latest label for specific project:

```
#Add Reference Assemblies to be loaded accordingly based on your VS client.

add-type -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll'
add-type -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll'

$CollectionUrl = 'http://servername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection'
$tfs = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($CollectionUrl)
$vcs = $tfs.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer])
$labels = $vcs.QueryLabels('*','$/ProjectName',$null,$true)
$latestlabel = $labels | Select-Object -first 1

write-host "The Latest Lable Name:" $latestlabel.Name
write-host "The Latest Lable ID  :" $latestlabel.LabelID
```

Comment: Hi  @Andy-MSFT:: I tried mentioned command before as well but it is giving me blank values. Please check and help me understand if i am missing anything here( i have mentioned only lines which i modified)-

$CollectionUrl = 'http://servername:8080/tfs' 
$tfs = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($CollectionUrl) 
$vcs = $tfs.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer]) 
$labels = $vcs.QueryLabels('*','$/project path/project.sln',$null,$true) 
$latestlabel = $labels | Select-Object -first 1

Comment: @PratikBompilwar Please also change the '$/ProjectName' to the real project name, but not '$/project path/project.sln', eg : if the project name is   "Test" ,just set it as $/Test

Comment: Thanks, @Andy-MSFT. That works. Do you have any idea if I can use any filter for label name. Let's say I want to search some label which starts from "test***.***.*". Can we use any contains(test) something like that?